# jquery events not triggering after load function call

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload

I have a situation where a input box is validated for input and if a matching input is found it should display sub options. Now I'm using the following function to reload a part of my jsp:

```
$("#directoryFilter").load("directory/filters #directoryFilter",{"selectId":selectId});
```

After the corresponding sub filters have loaded the jquery events stop triggering.

Comment: If you are adding elements dinamically you have to use the event "on"

Comment: im a bit new to jqeury can you help me in calling the above function with on

Comment: ok, but you have to give me more info about your source code

Comment: on the inital page i have a text box and a onclick event is triggered when a user clicks on it which displays a drop down menu with options. Not all the options have suboptions so if the selected input has suboption the portion of the jsp which is with the id - #directoryFilter is to be reloaded with the suboptions. please let me know what else you need

Comment: How do you execute the event click?  like this? $('#someid').click(function(){//do something});

Comment: $('#personType').on({
  'click' : persons.loadTypeDropdown,
 });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51509/discussion-between-alexander-ceballos-and-user2707760)